# BindingList<object> doesn't work for me

Tags: c#, wpf, object, wpf-controls, bindinglist

I have a class that interacts with a tableView. I have multiple pages in my program that uses this class/control. Problem was I was using `List<>` in this class to assign it to the itemsource. Later on I noticed I had to use `BindingLists` instead of Lists in order to be able to edit in the table for the end user.

Since I'm using different type of objects now I'm getting a lot of errors saying that it cannot implicitly convert to `BindingList<object>`, e.g.

```
Error   14  Cannot implicitly convert type     'System.ComponentModel.BindingList<Entity.Employee>' to     'System.ComponentModel.BindingList<object>'  ...\frmMainWindow.xaml.cs
```

Which is really weird because it worked quite fine when I was using List.
I cannot declare the BindingList as Employee since I'm using more types.

Is there a way to still use `BindingLists<>` and works well like Lists<>?

EDITION:

```
List<vCalendarPeriod> temp_list = RPTDAL.Get_CalendarPeriodByCalendarName_View("Monthly");
BindingList<vCalendarPeriod> temp_blist = new BindingList<vCalendarPeriod>(temp_list);
catalogGridAdministrationCalendarsMonthly.ItemsSource = temp_blist;
```

The error is marking temp_blist, and the error is the one i described earlier.

Comment: I think you can use simple List<CustomClass> but in order to edit CustomClass properties INotifyPropertyChanged should be implemented in that class for the fields you want to be editable

Comment: Those CustomClasses are auto-generated from a Database using an entity. Is there still a way to still implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Some some code, at least show us that line of code that is causing the error, also show the code that was working too.

Comment: I've added the part of the code that marks the error. Let me know if you want me to add more.

Comment: I changed everything to type object and it's fine now. Only aditional change was:

    List<object> temp_list = new List<object> ( RPTDAL.Get_CalendarPeriodByCalendarName_View("Monthly"));